# Find out pages used by mem_map[] array

Tags: linux, memory-management, kernel

Recently, I am working on the ARM Linux kernel, and I need to split the HighMem zone into two parts. So I have added a new zone into the kernel, let's say "NewMem". Therefore, I have three zones in my system, they are Normal, NewMem, and HighMem. The size of the NewMem zone is 512MB (, totally 131072 pages). My propose is that I want to manage all the page frames in NewMem zone in my own way, currently I use a doubly linked list to allocate/de-allocate pages. Note that the buddy system for NewMem zone is still exist, but I do not use it. To achieve this. I modified the page allocation routine to make sure that the kernel cannot allocate any page frame from my zone.

My concern is that can I use all the page frames in that zone as it is suggested that each zone is concerned with a subset of the mem_map[] array. I found that only 131084 pages are free in NewMem zone.Therefore, some page frames in my zone may used to store mem_map[], writing data to these pages may lead to unpredictable errors. So is there exist any way to find out which page frame is used to store mem_map[], so that I can avoid rewriting it.

Comment: There is *global* `mem_map` array, so it doesn't occupy your memory zone.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check the break down of physical and virtual memory. usually `mem_map` is stored on first *mappable* address of the virtual memory. In Unix, kernel image of usually 8MB is stored at physical address of **1MiB** accessed with virtual address `PAGE_OFFSET + 0x00100000`. **8MiB** is reserved in virtual memory for kernel image. Then comes the **16 MiB** of `zone_dma`. So first address which can be used by kernel for mapping is `0xC1000000`. Which is supposed to contain `mem_map` array.
I am not familiar with ARM memory break down but from your post it is evident that there is no `zone_dma` at least in your case. So your best bet is that address `0xC0800000` stores `mem_map`. I am assuming that kernel image is **8MB**.
As stated above in general first *mappable* virtual address stores `mem_map`. You can calculate that address with size and location of kernel image and `zone_dma`(present or not).
Please come with your feedback.